# Expo: How to detect a user closed browser event on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a credit card addition system with 3DS security enabled.

To achieve that, I have to open a browser to the bank 3DS system.

As the user has the possibility to close the opened browser tab, I have to be able to detect this event and reset the loading state.

I did it that way:

```js
client.service('credit-cards')
  .patch(creditCardRef.current._id, {
    registrationId: creditCardRef.current.registrationId,
    registrationData: registrationDataRef.current,
    registrationIpAddress: ipAddressRef.current,
    // @ts-expect-error Unable to set the type of the parsed query.
    registrationBrowserInfo: {
      ...parsedUrl.query,
      acceptHeader: headersRef.current.accept,
    },
    secureModeRedirectUrl: Linking.createURL('paybox-3ds', {
      queryParams: { creditCardId: creditCardRef.current._id },
    }),
  })
  .then(ResultHelpers.toOne)
  .then((result) => WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(result.secureModeUrl, {
    // @see https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8072#issuecomment-621173298
    showInRecents: true,
  }))
  .then((browserResult: WebBrowser.WebBrowserResult): void => {
    // On IOS check if the user manually closed the browser using "Done" browser button
    if (browserResult.type === 'cancel') {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    handleCreditCardRegistrationError(error);
  });
```

This is working, but only for iOS. Indeed, the [official documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#webbrowseropenbrowserasyncurl-browserparams) says:

> The promise behaves differently based on the platform.
>
> On Android promise resolves with `{type: 'opened'}` if we were able to
> open browser.
>
> On iOS: If the user closed the web browser, the Promise resolves with
> `{ type: 'cancel' }`.

What is my alternative for Android?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? It appears the documentation is still the same.